# When trying to update a DATE from C# code to an oracle database application gets stuck

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

So i wanna update a date field in my oracle database from my application so i use the following query and code

```
string insertqeuryrepair = "UPDATE REPARATIE SET PROBLEEM ='" + problem + "',DATUM = '11-12-2015' WHERE ONDERHOUDID=" + maintenanceID.ToString();
OracleSQL.modifyQuery(insertqeuryrepair);
```

and my modifyQeury function is as follows

```
 public static Boolean modifyQuery(String query)
    {
        bool succes = false;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, connection);
        try
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            succes = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[OracleSQL]Error, message: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        return succes;
    }
```

Now when i run this code the application gets stuck the thing however is when i remove DATE = '11-12-2015' it works just fine. '
How would i go about updating the date withouth the application getting stuck

Comment: What is the type of `DATUM` column? And other column types? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I hope that `problem` does not come from user supplied data, otherwise you're looking at SQL injection issues.

Comment: Always use ISO format for dates (YYYY-MM-DD) to have less problems.

Comment: The way I use the sql query is after advice from a buddy of mine. I said the same thing that this sort of thing is very vurnable to sql-injection so i tried to do some injections myself however these all got filtered

Comment: BTW the type of the DATUM column is DATE

Answer (score 0):

What if you explicitly set the format of DATUM using [TO_DATE()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php), like this

```
string insertqeuryrepair = "UPDATE REPARATIE SET PROBLEEM ='" + problem + "',DATUM = TO_DATE('11-12-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') WHERE ONDERHOUDID=" + maintenanceID.ToString();
```

Comment: Unfortunatlly this still gets the application stuck

Comment: What kind of exception does it produce?

Answer (score 0):

First, parameterize your Update query using colons to represent OracleParameter ParameterName values:

```
string insertqueryrepair = "UPDATE REPARATIE SET PROBLEEM = :problem, DATUM = :myDate WHERE ONDERHOUDID= :maintenanceID";
```

Next, parse your date to a `DateTime` variable:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse("11/12/2015");
```

Third, set a return bool variable and call your function, but rename it `doQuery`, not `modifyQuery`, as you shouldn't be modifying anything in it - just setting the parameters and executing it:

```
bool succes = OracleSQL.doQuery(insertqueryrepair, myDate, problem, maintenanceID.ToString());
```

Now we pass in your values to the function and parameterize them:

```
public static Boolean doQuery(string query, string problem, string maintenanceID, DateTime myDate)
{
    bool succes = false;
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, connection);
    try
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();

        OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter();
        param1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Nvarchar2;
        param1.ParameterName = "problem";
        param1.Value = problem;

        OracleParameter param2 = new OracleParameter();
        param2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Nvarchar2;
        param2.ParameterName = "maintenanceID";
        param2.Value = maintenanceID;

        OracleParameter param3 = new OracleParameter();
        param3.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
        param3.ParameterName = "myDate";
        param3.Value = myDate;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        succes = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[OracleSQL]Error, message: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    return succes;
}
```

You could even go the extra step and make the passed in variables generic (param1, param2, etc.), and do checks on them for nulls so if you pass in a different query with maybe 1 value (and the rest can be set to null) to this function, it doesn't have to operate on 3 variables all the time.  This function could do all your work for any query you have if you set it up right.